# Is there a way to use PyTables to create a specified group if it does not already exist, or open an existing group if it does?

Tags: python, hdf5, pytables

PyTables has a [`create_group`](https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/libref/file_class.html?highlight=create_group#tables.File.create_group) method to create a group, but it only works if the group does not already exist.

I don't see an `open_group` method (other than the access-by-attribute approach as in `h5file.root.g1.g2` which would access the group `/g1/g2`); is there a clean way to create a group if it doesn't exist, but return the existing group if it does?

Comment: Have you considered `File.__contains__(path)` to test for a Node with the desired path name, then create the group or return it as appropriate? Alternately, if you're creating a group and then going to create a data object (Table, Array, etc), you can skip the `create_group` step and use `createparents=True` when you create the data object. PyTables will create the group for you (if needed). :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `createparents` and doing something like this:

```
def createGroup(self, path):
    try:
        return self.hfile.get_node(path)
    except pt.NoSuchNodeError:
        parent, nodename = path.rsplit('/',1)
        if parent == '':
            parent = '/'
        return self.hfile.create_group(parent, nodename, createparents=True)
```

Comment: I get deduced what `path` is...What is `self` in `createGroup(self, path)`? Also, is `hfile` the file object returned from `tb.open_file()`? Are you assuming it has global scope?

Comment: it's not global scope; `createGroup` is a method of my object and `hfile` is a property, and yes' it's obtained by `open_file()`

Comment: Got it, this is an object method. I was trying it out, and couldn't get it to work as-is. There's more to your process than this snippet. Thanks for the details.

Answer (score 2):

Jason, here's a little code snippet that demonstrates both the `createparents` argument with the `create_table()` method and `File.__contains__(path)` to check 3 different group names and print results.

```
import tables as tb
import numpy as np
h5f = tb.open_file('SO_54080906.h5','w')

ds_dtype = np.dtype([('a',float),('b',float),('c',float)])
arr = np.array(np.arange(30.0).reshape(10,3))
recarr = np.core.records.array(arr,dtype=ds_dtype)

#create agroup at root level
h5f.create_group(h5f.root, 'agroup')

#create dataset 1 at root.bgroup level
dataset1 = h5f.create_table('/bgroup', 'dataset1',
                            createparents=True, obj=recarr )

for grpname in ['/agroup', '/bgroup' , '/cgroup']:
    if h5f.__contains__(grpname) :
      print ('found path for:', grpname)
    else:
      print ('path doesnt exist for:', grpname)

h5f.close()
```

Output looks like this:

```
found path for: /agroup
found path for: /bgroup
path doesnt exist for: /cgroup
```